# Ajax Post Request from domain(localhost:9393) to another domain(localhost:9696): Spring Rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring

I have a form in one app running in localhost:9393
JS function to post data is:

```js
function registerClient() {
  var postData = $("#client-reg").serializeArray();
  var formURL = "http://localhost:9393/mPaws/client/register?type=eSchool";
  $.ajax({
   url : formURL,
   type : 'POST',
   beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   },
   data : postData,
   success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data);
    registrationSuccessPage();
   },
   error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(errorThrown);
   }
  });

 }
```

And i have post method in spring controller:

```js
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9696")
 @RequestMapping(value = "/client/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody ValidationResponse registerClient(@ModelAttribute("user")User user, BindingResult errors, @Param String type) {
  ValidationResponse response = new ValidationResponse();
  getUserValidator().validate(user, errors);
  if(errors.hasErrors()) {
   response.setStatus("FAIL");
   List<FieldError> allErrors = errors.getFieldErrors();
   List<ErrorMessage> errorMesages = new ArrayList<ErrorMessage>();
   for (FieldError objectError : allErrors) {
    errorMesages.add(new ErrorMessage(objectError.getField(), objectError.getDefaultMessage()));
   }
   response.setErrorMessageList(errorMesages);
  }else {
   Role role = new Role();

   if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("eSchool")) {
    role.setId(3);
    user.setType("eSchool");
   }else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("ePathLab")) {
    role.setId(1);
    user.setType("ePathLab");
   }else {
    role.setId(0);
   }

   User savedUser = null;
   if(role.getId() > 0) {
    user.setPassword(getUserService().getEncryptedPassword(user.getPassword()));
    user.setEnabled(false);
    user.setRole(role);
    
    savedUser = getUserService().addUser(user);
   }
   if(savedUser != null) {
    boolean mailSent = true;
    if(mailSent){
     response.setStatus("SUCCESS");
    }
   }else {
    response.setStatus("FAIL");
   }
  }
  return response;
 }
```

On pressing submit i am getting error:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9393/mPaws/client/register. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9696' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

Please help me with this.

Comment: I think this is caused by same origin policy.I heard there is a technique called CORS to relax it, but I cannot say more since I never used that

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide cross domain access. You can do this by adding header to your response.

- Access-Control-Allow-Origin
- Access-Control-Allow-Methods
- Access-Control-Max-Age
- Access-Control-Allow-Headers

  ```
  response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

  response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, HEAD");
  response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-PINGOTHER, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  response.addHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The ajax post function:

```js
function registerClient() {
  var postData = $("#client-reg").serializeArray();
  var formURL = "http://localhost:9393/mPaws/client/register?type=eSchool";
  $.ajax({
   url : formURL,
   type : 'POST',
   data : postData,
   headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "*"
   },
   success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data);
    registrationSuccessPage();
   },
   error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(errorThrown);
   }
  });

 }
```

And the post method in spring controller:

```js
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:9696")
 @RequestMapping(value = "/client/register", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*"})
 @ResponseBody ValidationResponse registerClient(@ModelAttribute("user")User user, BindingResult errors, @Param String type) {
  ValidationResponse response = new ValidationResponse();
  getUserValidator().validate(user, errors);
  if(errors.hasErrors()) {
   response.setStatus("FAIL");
   List<FieldError> allErrors = errors.getFieldErrors();
   List<ErrorMessage> errorMesages = new ArrayList<ErrorMessage>();
   for (FieldError objectError : allErrors) {
    errorMesages.add(new ErrorMessage(objectError.getField(), objectError.getDefaultMessage()));
   }
   response.setErrorMessageList(errorMesages);
  }else {
   Role role = new Role();

   if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("eSchool")) {
    role.setId(3);
    user.setType("eSchool");
   }else if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("ePathLab")) {
    role.setId(1);
    user.setType("ePathLab");
   }else {
    role.setId(0);
   }

   User savedUser = null;
   if(role.getId() > 0) {
    user.setPassword(getUserService().getEncryptedPassword(user.getPassword()));
    user.setEnabled(false);
    user.setRole(role);
    
    savedUser = getUserService().addUser(user);
   }
   if(savedUser != null) {
    boolean mailSent = true;
    if(mailSent){
     response.setStatus("SUCCESS");
    }
   }else {
    response.setStatus("FAIL");
   }
  }
  return response;
 }
```

Working fine.

Comment: is the answer to your issue?